# Search entire listview

Tags: c#, listview

Can someone please explain to me why my code doesn't search the entire objects within the `ListView`. Basically I am trying to locate all text matching the string entered in the textbox. Currently, the code only searches the first column and stop...

how can I get it to search all 5 columns?

See code below:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = "    Search Via Forename";
    int result = 0;
    int count = 0;
    result = string.Compare(textBox1.Text, s);

    if ((result == 0) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))){
        MessageBox.Show("Please input forename...");
        return;
    }

    foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items){
        foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subItem in item.SubItems){
            if (item.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToLower())){
                count++;
                statusBar1.Panels[2].Text = "Found: " + count.ToString();
            }else{
                listView1.Items.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }

    button1.Text = "Clear";
    textBox1.Visible = false;
    button3.Visible = false;
    button2.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: how do you populate the `ListView` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> explain to me why my code doesn't search the entire objects within thelistview

because you never use `subItem` inside your loop. I guess you meant to compare the `subItem` instead of `item`:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items){
    foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subItem in item.SubItems){

              ---- use subItem here        
              |
              v
        if (subItem.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToLower())){
            count++;
            statusBar1.Panels[2].Text = "Found: " + count.ToString();
        }else{
            listView1.Items.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @BOB.G you loop through all `ListViewSubItem` of every item, which basically checks each column. but you don't use this variable. In the code you posted you check whether a row **starts with** a certain text. But you want to check whether any of the rows starts with this text, so use the iterator from you second loop

Comment: Tried your modification.... thinking about it, it make a lot of sense, however, it gave me a blank list. I suppose I'll have to do some more thinking. Before it use to display found objects only from the first column

Comment: @BOB.G what is a blank list? was the list empty? It is important to know how you populated the ListView?=!! Did you use subitems, or did you simply added items and used the ToString method for display?

Comment: The counter indicates that the loop is working. The program is just not displaying the results now.

Comment: Excuse my terminology.... blank list meant it wasn't displaying the results. The listview is populated by another procedure within the program, so there will always be a listview with 35 objects/entries.